# Finding Variance of the Hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, proof-explanation, variance

I've been trying to find the variance of the Hypergeometric distribution, but have had issues calculating $\ E [X^2]$.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Variance of Hypergeometric or Geometric?

Comment: Indeed.  There is quite a difference.  (Title and tag do not agree with body text.)

Comment: If you include some working for $\mathsf E(X^2)$ we can see what you are doing.  Add some more details.

Comment: @Mark hyper thank you

Comment: sorry guys im new here and have trouble writing down the formulas

Comment: That's okay.  You have but to try.  Also research: 
[Basic Tutorial And Quick Reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @GrahamKemp thank you !

Comment: take a look here: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380460/derivation-of-mean-and-variance-of-hypergeometric-distribution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380460/derivation-of-mean-and-variance-of-hypergeometric-distribution)

Comment: @Momo thank you i understood what i needed. it was the part where you had to play with combination formula to get another combination formulas for the $E[X^2]$

Comment: @Grahamkemp thank you again I found what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Hypergeometric Distribution, with population $N$, population favoured items $K$, and sample size $n$.

Let $X_i$ be the indicator that the $i$-th item in the sample is favoured, for $i\in\{1, .., n\}$

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

We note that $\mathsf P(X_i{=}1)= K/N$ and $\mathsf P(X_i{=}1, X_j{=}1) = K(K-1)/N(N-1)$ (for all $i\neq j)$ and because $X_\star$ are indicator random variables:

$$\mathsf E(X_i) = \frac KN$$

$$\mathsf E(X_iX_{j:j\neq i}) = \frac {K(K-1)}{N(N-1)}$$

Then $$\mathsf E(X^2) = \mathsf E\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\right)\right) =\quad\lower{2ex}\ldots$$