# Expected value and variance of number of randomly drawn balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

The urn contains $N$ balls including $b$ white balls. We pick without replacement $n$ balls $(n \leq N)$. Define random variable $X$ as a number of white balls picked. Find expected value and variance of $X$.

I found that 
$$P(X=k)=\frac{\binom{b}{k}\binom{N-b}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{k}},$$
so the expected value will be $$EX=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\binom{b}{k}\binom{N-b}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{k}} k.$$
My questions are, how can this expression be simplified, and how do I calculate the variance?

Comment: You can use linearity of expectation for a much simpler calculation of the expectation

Comment: You can use the Computational Formula ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_formula_for_the_variance) to try and find the variance.

Comment: @Henry I tried doing that, I defined rv $X_i=1$ if the $i-$th ball is white and $0$ otherwise, but I have trouble calculating $P(X_i=1)$, because result of $i-$th draw depends on previous $i-1$ draws.

Comment: [There](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1380505/696469) he says " They expected number of black balls on any one trial is a/N, so just add that up n times." I don't get why is it always $a/N$. Why is that, if we picked black balls in some previous trials then in the $i-th$ trial we don't have $N$ balls to pick to nor $a$ black balls.