# In a company, 30% of 800 men have a specific marker in their Y chromossome. Find the variance of the number of men that have this marker in a sample

Tags: probability, statistics

> A company employs 800 men younger than 55. Suppose that 30% of these
>   men have a marker in the Y chromosome that indicates a higher risk of
>   high blood pressure.
>
> a) If 10 men are tested, what is the probability that exactly 3 have
>   the marker?
>
> b) If 20 men are tested, what is the variance of the number of men
>   that have the marker?

At first I thought I was supposed to use a binomial distribution and got .266828 for a) and 21/5 for b. I checked the solutions and this was wrong. So for a) I did:

$$\frac{\binom{240}{3}\binom{560}{7}}{\binom{800}{10}} = 0.268510$$

which apparently is the right answer... somehow.

Not sure how to go about b).

Why is that correct for a) (makes little sense to me to use this method when the probability using the binomial distribution is so similar and imo the binomial distribution suits this better) and how do I solve b)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sampling is from a finite population without replacement.  Therefore, the distribution of the number of men with the marker is hypergeometric.

To calculate the probability from first principles, note that if we have a population of $n$ employees, $m$ of which have the marker, and you sample $s$ employees at random without replacement, then the outcomes in which $x$ of the $s$ employees have the marker can be enumerated as follows.  There are $\binom{m}{x}$ ways to select $x$ employees with the marker from the group of such employees.  There are $\binom{n-m}{s-x}$ ways to select the $s-x$ employees in the sample without the marker from the group of employees lacking it.  Since these choices are independent, the total number of ways to choose $s$ employees such that exactly $x$ have the marker is $\binom{m}{x}\binom{n-m}{s-x}$.  Then since the total number of ways to choose $s$ employees out of $n$ total without regard to who has the marker is $\binom{n}{s}$, it follows that the probability that $x$ employees have the marker is $$\Pr[X = x] = \frac{\binom{m}{x}\binom{n-m}{s-x}}{\binom{n}{s}}$$ where $$X \sim \operatorname{Hypergeometric}(n,m,s)$$ is a random variable counting the number of employees in the sample that have the marker.

In your case, we have $$n = 800, \quad m = (0.3)(800) = 240, \quad s = 10$$ for the first part, and we wish to find $$\Pr[X = 3] = \frac{\binom{240}{3}\binom{560}{7}}{\binom{800}{10}}.$$

In the second case, we have $s = 20$ and we want to find $\operatorname{Var}[X]$.  The derivation of the mean and variance of the hypergeometric distribution may be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380460/derivation-of-mean-and-variance-of-hypergeometric-distribution/1669384#1669384).  In particular, in the notation we have adopted here, $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \frac{ms(n-m)(n-s)}{n^2 (n-1)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this solution is right. I'm my experience textbook answers are created in a vacuum which makes finding the "right" answer extremely subjective (which means you should ask the person who made the question lol).

The binomial distribution is usually used to test a null hypothesis.

$\Pr(X=k)={\binom {n}{k}}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$

The question seems to be sampling from the same population from which the percentage is derived.

The equation you posted looks similar to Bayes theorem.

$P(A\mid B)={\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}}$

The numerator is calculating the frequency of 3 positive samples from 240 positives, 7 negative samples from 560 negatives, and 10 samples from 800 samples. However, if you have all combinations of 3 positives and 7 negatives, then you also have all the ways you can select 10 samples.

For b,

You need to get the variance in the number of men that have the marker. I would use the binomial equation for variance, var=n*p*(1-p). Again, I’m not sure if this would be the correct formula for this case.

Python Code:

```
from scipy import stats
#a
r = stats.binom.pmf(3,10, 0.3)
print(r)
#b
print(np.var(stats.binom.rvs(20, 0.3,size=1000)))
```

Comment: Could you expand on how you solved b)? And yeah I will ask my professor about this.

Answer (score 0):

I asked my professor. He said to use the hypergeometric distribution with N = 600 and K = 240. Yeah makes sense actually because you don't test the same man twice, so the probability changes.