# A Hypergeometric probability distribution and Zeilberger

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, random-variables, means, hypergeometric-function

On page 107 of book 'The Concrete Tetrahedron' by Manuel Kauers . Peter Paule

A Hypergeometric probability distribution is given : consider
an urn containing N balls, m green ones and $N - m$ blue ones. If we select a ball at
random, we will clearly hit a green ball with probability $ m/N$ and a blue ball with
probability $ (N - m)/N$. In general, if we select n balls,
then the probability of k green balls is

\begin{gather}\frac{ \binom{m}{ k} \binom{N-m}{n- k}} {\binom{N}{n}}\end{gather}
This much I understand. Next gives the mean

\begin{gather}\sum_{k=0}^n k\frac{ \binom{m}{ k} \binom{N-m}{n- k}} 
{\binom{N}{n}}=\frac{nm}{N} \end{gather}

which I understand why it's calculated that way but don't understand how he so easily
gets the rhs and mainly why he says Zeilberger's algorithm will do the last step for us.
What is Zeilberger about it ? I read his description of Zeilberger's algorithm prior and some example(s) but can hardly understand much if any about it. Perhaps if someone can explain it wrt this it may help. Before Zeilberger was there any other way to get the rhs in closed form for any $m,N,n$ ??

Next he calculates the variance

\begin{gather}\sum_{k=0}^n( k-\frac{nm}{N})^2\frac{ \binom{m}{ k} \binom{N-m}{n- k}} {\binom{N}{n}}=\frac{mn(N-n)(N-m)}{N^2(N-1)} \end{gather}
and says again Zeilberger's algorithm saves us from having to perform any hand calculations. How is this and again  before Zeilberger was there any other way to get the rhs in closed form for any $m,N,n$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivation of mean and variance of Hypergeometric Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380460/derivation-of-mean-and-variance-of-hypergeometric-distribution)

Comment: ok except for the Zeilberger inference i have gotten thru the mean part and now i do remember going thru that in college as i thought i did prior and also now recall the variance part. Next i need what Zeilberger has to do with it so i may begin to understand what or atleast part of what his derivation is about

Comment: Anyway i know it was derived long before his algorithm was in existence and likely before he was even born as i was fairly certain but was not positively sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Zeilberger's algorithm but we can calculate the mean and variance as follows.

If $X$ is a hypergeometric random variable with the parameters defined as above then \begin{align*}
E[X] &= \sum_{k=0}^n k\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{\frac{m(m-1)!}{(m-k)!k(k-1)!}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\frac{N(N-1)!}{(N-n)!n(n-1)!}}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n n\frac{m}{N}\frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N-1}{n-1}}\\
&= n\frac{m}{N}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N-1}{n-1}}\\
&= n\frac{m}{N}.
\end{align*} The last equality follows from the summation equalling $1$ since it is the sum over all the probabilities.

Then $Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = E[X(X-1) + X] - E[X]^2 = E[X(X-1)] + E[X](1-E[X])$. Now
\begin{align*}
E[X(X-1)] &= \sum_{k=0}^n k(k-1)\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n k(k-1)\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n (k-1)\frac{m\binom{m-1}{k-1}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{m(m-1)\binom{m-2}{k-2}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{m(m-1)\binom{m-2}{k-2}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\frac{N}{n}\frac{N-1}{n-1}\binom{N-2}{n-2}}\\
&= \frac{m(m-1)n(n-1)}{N(N-1)}
\end{align*}
so \begin{align*}Var[X] &= \frac{m(m-1)n(n-1)}{N(N-1)} + \frac{mn}{N}\left(1- \frac{mn}{N}\right)\\ &= \frac{Nm(m-1)n(n-1) + mnN(N-1) - m^2n^2(N-1)}{N^2(N-1)}\\
&= \frac{mn(N(m-1)(n-1) + N(N-1) - mn(N-1))}{N^2(N-1)}\\
&= \frac{mn(N^2 - Nm - Nn + mn)}{N^2(N-1)}\\
&= \frac{mn(N-m)(N-n)}{N^2(N-1)}.
\end{align*}