# Convergence in probability for $Y(Y-1)/(n(n-1)$ where $Y$ is a Bin$(n,p)$ random variable

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Let $ x_1,x_2,...,x_n  $ be iid Bernoulli random variables with success probability p. Let $$ Y = \sum{X_i} $$ We want to show that

$$ \frac{Y(Y-1)}{n(n-1)} $$ converges in probability to $p^2$ as n tends to infinity.

**My attempt is that:**

Let $Z = \frac{Y(Y-1)}{n(n-1)} $ where
$$ 0<= P(|Z - p^2| - \epsilon) <= \frac{Var(Z)}{\epsilon^2} = \frac{Var(Y(Y-1))}{n^2(n-1)^2\epsilon^2} $$
where I use Chebyshev inequality to show that the upper limit will converge to 0 as n tends to infinity. But I think I am unable to show that $Var(Y(Y-1))$ is finite since $Var(Y^2) = E(X^4) - (E(X^2))^2 $ which I think is tedious to get the $E(X^4)$, is there any concise way to show the term $Var(Y(Y-1))$ is finite.

Comment: $Y/n$ converges almost surely (or in probability) to $p$. Similarly, so does $(Y-1)/(n-1)$. You can use the fact that limit of product is product of limits.

Comment: @AndrewZhang already gave a great hint. However, if you know statistics, the expression is the MVUE of $p^2$ and the result comes immediately.

Comment: $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i=\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: 1) X is a binomial Bin(n,p) distribution. 2) I don't understand at all your title: where do we square a Bernoulli variable ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I think since $X_i$ is Bernoulli, so Y which is the sum of n $x_i$ is binomial variable. To find $Y^2$, it is a squared binomial variable.

Comment: This question has something in common with answers to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1380460/305862 dealing with an hypergeometric R.V.

Answer (score 2):

There are easier ways to show the desired convergence. For example, you can do this by expanding on the following points:

- $\frac{Y}{n}\to p$ in probability as $n\to\infty$ by law of large numbers.
- Similarly, $\frac{Y-1}{n-1}=\frac{\frac Yn-\frac1n}{1-\frac1n} \to p$ in probability as $n\to\infty$.
- The product $\frac{Y}{n}\cdot\frac{Y-1}{n-1}$ therefore converges in probability to $p\cdot p=p^2$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: If $Y:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{Y}{n}= 0$ surely.

Comment: @Michael But here it's not a simple $Y$, it's a $Y_n$ with $E(Y_n)=n/2$...

Comment: I wish your notation had reflected that, then.

Answer (score 2):

Proof that $X_n \rightarrow c_1$ and $Z_n \rightarrow c_2$ then $X_n Z_n \rightarrow c_1c_2$, if either $X_n$ or $Z_n$ is a bounded random variable:

$P(|X_n Z_n-c_1 c_2| \geq \epsilon) = P(|X_n Z_n-X_nc_2+X_nc_2-c_1 c_2|\geq \epsilon)$
$= P(|X_n(Z_n-c_2)+c_2(X_n-c_1)| \geq \epsilon) \leq P(|X_n(Z_n-c_2)|\geq \epsilon/2)+P(|c_2(X_n-c_1)| \geq \epsilon/2)$

Since $|X_n| \leq 1$, we have that,

$\leq P(|(Z_n-c_2)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2})+P(|c_2(X_n-c_1)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \rightarrow 0 $

This combined with @StubbornAtom answer concludes the proof.